# Which recursion is better? global variable or local variables

Tags: java, recursion

I have been programming in Java for quite a while but I have always stayed away from recursion. I recently figured out that recursion is very nifty in solving problems so I took to practicing it.

I narrowed it down to 2 ways:

1) using global variables

2) using local variables

I wrote a simple program that coverts a string to its respective Int value

```
private static int integerNumber; // <---global variable

//****the global variable way****

public static void StringToInt(String s) {

    if (s.length()==1) {
        System.out.println("The integer number is ="+(integerNumber+Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0))));
        integerNumber=integerNumber+Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
    } else {
        integerNumber+=(Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0))*(int)Math.pow(10, s.length()-1));
        StringToInt(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

and the following is the local variable way:

```
public static int StringToInteger(String s) { // ****local variable way****
    int intNum=0;// <--- local variable
    if (s.length()==1){
        intNum=Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
        return intNum;
    }else{
        return intNum=(int) (Math.pow(10,s.length()-1)*Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)))+StringToInteger(s.substring(1));
    }
```

Which method is space efficient and why?

Comment: Consider what happens if you're doing this in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: It will depend on how you will use them. For example, you can store the ending result in a `List` but for current solution (current recursive call) you can store the data in a local `List`.

Comment: A list is a bad example for a recursion. You know Start and end, no difference to a loop.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I don't have experience with multithread programming. Could you clarify . 
I want to know which method will consume least space LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @PeterRader in dynamic programming you need to keep the results of the previous operations, and there you can use a `List` or a `Map` and navigate through it to find the best solution for your specific case. Also, the current algorithm to find a solution may be implemented using recursive methods. I cannot find having a `List` as a bad example for recursion, probably not wide used it.

Comment: This comparison is a micro optimization (aside from issues with static and multithreading as Oli points out). Neither will be different enough as they are both essentially taking the same exact approach.

Comment: @AneeshK in the example you post, it is worthless calculating space. To begin with, `static` recursive methods should not maintain state through the calls so you **must** avoid the first option, basically because it will generate lot of problems in a multi threaded environment. And, again, it will depend on what you need to store and with that on mind you design your algorithm.

Comment: I used static just for testing the program with a 'main' method from the same class...

Comment: Then you need more practice on Java...

Comment: could you suggest some reference

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You can not find a example for a recursion for a list? Its because noone uses a recursion for a list! Give me an example where it is better to use a recursive method instead of a loop for a list.

Comment: @PeterRader looks like you didn't understand my comment. And, for your question, practice some programming in Lisp or Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the space efficiency goes, on the surface, the first one is slightly more space-efficient, because the second way requires an extra local variable `intNum` at each level of invocation.

However, since the assignment of `intNum` happens right before the return, Java compilers are free to optimize it out entirely: your code is equivalent to this:

```
if (s.length()==1){
    return Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
}else{
    return (int) (Math.pow(10,s.length()-1)*Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)))+StringToInteger(s.substring(1));
}
```

Generally, though, one should be very careful using any state outside the recursive method itself, including instance variables, because reliance on keeping the external state makes your recursive code harder to understand.

Comment: Ok...so you're saying that I should always look to follow the local variable method for recursion. Is there any other way to save the space on every call

Comment: @AneeshK As far as saving space goes, the best advise is not about extra variables on a stack frame, but about the number of stack frames that you need, i.e. the maximum depth of an invocation. You should not use recursion if the maximum depth grows linearly with the size of your data structure (unless it's a tail call and you're on a modern compiler that optimize it). When the depth of an invocation grows as Log2(N), adding a few scalar variables onto the stack is not going to make much difference.